# Why remove the first space from strings.xml

Tags: kotlin, android-resources

When I call something from the string.xml I get less, remove, the first space. Why?

```
<string name="s_basket_hun"> kosara</string>
<string name="s_basket_en">s basket</string>//removed the apostrophe

val cellValue = CustomerName + resources.getString(R.string.s_basket_hun)
```

I get just "kosara" instead " kosara"

There may be some wildcards like & nbsp; in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal check the reference https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#escaping_quotes

> Whitespace collapsing and Android escaping happens after your resource
> file gets parsed as XML. This means that     
>   (space, punctuation space, Unicode Em space) all
> collapse to a single space (" "), because they are all Unicode spaces
> after the file is parsed as an XML. To preserve those spaces as they
> are, you can either quote them ("    
>  ") or use Android escaping ( \u0032 \u8200
> \u8195).

So you have three alternatives

1- Use `"`

```
<string name="s_basket_hun">" kosara"</string>
```

2- Use HTML Code `&quot;` (that is the same of `"`)

```
<string name="s_basket_hun">&quot; kosara&quot;</string>
```

3- Add space via code

```
val yourString = resources.getString(R.string.s_basket_hun)
val cellValue = "$CustomerName $yourString"
```

Comment: Vaaaoo, very fast answer. Thank you it's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

That's how the Android resource system works.

If you want to preserve trailing whitespace, you can enclose the value in double quotes, like

```
<string name="s_basket_hun">" kosara"</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resources trim that white space. I suggest you to.use this instead of concatenate customer name and string

```
<string name="s_basket_en">%s basket</string>

val cellValue = resources.getString(R.string.s_basket_hun, CustomerName)
```

But if you still want to use like that you can use this:

```
<string name="s_basket_en">&#160;kosara</string>
```

And you can get your string like this but Android Studio want you to use the first one anyway.

```
val cellValue = "$CustomerName ${resources.getString(R.string.s_basket_hun)}"
```